# No partition predicate found for Alias even when the partition predicate in present in the query

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hiveql, hue

I have a table pos.pos_inv in hdfs which is partitioned by yyyymm. Below is the query:

```
select DATE_ADD(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(Inv.actvydt, 'MM/dd/yyyy'))),5), 
       to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(Inv.actvydt, 'MM/dd/yyyy'))),yyyymm 
   from pos.pos_inv inv 
      INNER JOIN pos.POSActvyBrdg Brdg ON Brdg.EIS_POSActvyBrdgId = Inv.EIS_POSActvyBrdgId 
      where to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(Inv.nrmlzdwkenddt, 'MM/dd/yyyy'))) 
       BETWEEN DATE_SUB(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(Inv.actvydt, 'MM/dd/yyyy'))),6) 
        and DATE_ADD(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(Inv.actvydt, 'MM/dd/yyyy'))),6) 
        and inv.yyyymm=201501
```

I have provided the partition value for the query as 201501, but still i get the error"

```
 Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10041]: No partition predicate found for Alias "inv" Table "pos_inv"
```

(schema)The partition, yyyymm is int type and actvydt is date stored as string type.

Comment: jeff, which version of hive you are using , I think there are some open jira issues (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4905, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10454
) related to this issue when partition predicate column is used in the combination of Join, if you are using older version of hive try setting mapred mode to nonstrict and run the query `set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict`

Comment: If i use     set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict , then the whole data set is scanned rather than the particular partition value.

Comment: jeff, I thought its a workaround just for now ,  may be this patches are updated in latest version , which version of hive is yours , it it possible to try in the higher version?

Comment: Workaround:  Wrap the offending table in a subquery with the partition predicate, (select * from table where partition > value)
this avoids the error and avoids scanning the entire table.

Comment: If you you use the `nonstrict` workaround for queries sent with beeline from the command-line (like `beeline -u "jdbc:..." -e "select ..."`) you'll need to add it on the command-line: `--hivevar hive.mapred.mode=unstrict`

Answer (score 19):

This happens because hive is set to strict mode.
this allow the partition table to  access the respective partition /folder in hdfs .

```
  set hive.mapred.mode=unstrict;  it will work
```

Comment: -1 this is not the correct use. You should filter your select statement with appropriate predicate. For, example. if table has one predicate named  'dt' then Select * from MyTable where dt='2017/10/10'

Answer (score 1):

In your query error it is said: *No partition predicate found for Alias "inv" Table "pos_inv".*

So you must put the where clause for the fields of the partitioned table (for pos_inv), and not for the other one (inv), as you've done.

Answer (score 1):

set hive.mapred.mode=unstrict allows you access the whole data rather than the particular partitons. In some case read whole dataset is necessary, such as: rank() over

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the 2 tables have the same column name (possibly same partition column). Try to deal with separate tables with where condition like below

```
WITH tableA as
(
-- All your where clause here
),

tableB AS
(
-- All your where clause here
)
select tableA.*, tableB.*
```